# Typescript: Wrap function return type of generic class

Tags: typescript, mocking, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am not being able to wrap my head around this issue in a generic way with Typescript, I would appreciate any help!

- A Factory should deploy a Contract
- A CustomFactory is a Factory and should deploy a CustomContract (that is a Contract)
- A MockFactory should be a wrapper of all this logic

Something like this would be the goal (semi pseudocode)

```
interface MockFactory<F extends Factory> extends F {
    deploy: (...args: Parameters<F.prototype.deploy>) => MockContract<F.prototype.deploy.returnValue>
}
```

In order to illustrate the issue even better I created a [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtxUWZBvAXwFgAoU0SWRFAMR3SgE99Tk3kATCABwBt1GALmQAKAHQS4UAOYBnYXBCMA2gF0AlMgC8APjSYw2BGADcpYmRIJecWbLQBXWWHQBbDFhzJgrvhFcQ4PYehl6EpKTWtsFOLq50xgzMPn4BQcgJLkwsJOycPPyMIgAewiAOrgBG0AA0yELI5VXQ6sKosW4hRrh4rHnsUBBgDlAg%20ARmuewWFqRgjNwoALLoCADWXTgAPKjIEMWQIBzBBt16WvqexsgAZGi3OXmuq2sAClDoi1DzZRXVUJNZiQKNB4EhkCt1pkklsaHsDoFjhl6Ew9PtDki4b0pmwAPS4-J8ATIWQAC3QDl4HGQpLgADcUGBSShuFI4AFKPZ0DBkEyUDAHCBjMBMITCt4QLJgFwMqJQLzScB7AhbCh2s43NCmOo%20niCVwicwyRSqchBsNRsg4BCXptrtyFShzSMxvNFsgHXzkAKhWARWMDeLQFKZXCRJCNqdtuq4nawHp5dbpIFoMAEMgAO5wRg6nFigTCcSSGTyZCvNkc6CyWFibgfFxuiBiQMCHSaXQ29Zxmt19ANhZNluMMTO0YANTgvAcEB05iAA) where you can see the errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just solved by using ReturnType and Parameters, as well needed to transform the interface into a type:

```js
interface Contract {}

interface Factory {
    deploy: (...args: any[]) => Contract;
}

class CustomContract implements Contract {}

class CustomFactory implements Factory {
    deploy(x: number, y: number): CustomContract {
        return {};
    }
}

type MockContract<C extends Contract> = Contract & C & {
    mockProperty: number;
}

type MockFactory<F extends Factory> = F & {
    // deploy should have the parameters of the function deploy inside F (in this case CustomFactory)
    // deploy should return a MockContract of the return type of the function deploy inside F (MockContract<CustomContract> in a generic way)
    deploy: (...args: Parameters<F['deploy']>) => MockContract<ReturnType<F['deploy']>>
}

const example: MockFactory<CustomFactory> = {} as any;
example.deploy(1, 2);
```

[Updated Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtxUWZBvAXwFgAoU0SWRFAMR3SgE99Tk3kATCABwBt1GALmQAKAHQS4UAOYBnYXBCMA2gF0AlMgC8APjSYw2BGADcpYmRIJecWbLQBXWWHQBbDFhzJgrvhFcQ4PYehl6EpKTWtsFOLq50xgzMPn4BQcgJLkwsJOycPPyMIgAewiAOrgBG0AA0yELI5VXQ6sKosW4hRrh4rHnsUBBgDlAg%20ARmuewWFqRgjNwoALLoCADWXTgAPKjIEMWQIBzBBt16WvqexsgAZGi3OXmuq2sAClDoi1DzZRXVUJNZiR5otkCt1pkklsaHsDoFjhl6ExzhkHr0pmwAPSY-J8ATIWQAC3QDl4HGQhLgADcUGBCShuFI4AFKPZ0DBkHSUDAHCBjMBMLjCt4QLJgFxUSJQJzCcB7AhbCh2s43JCmOo%20licVw8cwiSSychBsNRsg4GCXptruyZShjSMxiCUDaucgeXywAKxjrhaAxRKYSJwRtTttlXErWA9NLzdJAtBgAhkAB3OCMDUYoUCYTiSQyeTIV5MlnQWTQ5QAch9Agrqh0ml0FvWka2ACUhg6ACoLCDlqsFGt1nTmCJWTDOWHMvzCYNqxg7DrxJGMFGEM32RSMSb7Ke8CBiatFACMdQATOpJkA)

Comment: Please dont forget to share your code in your answer as well. Playground links sometimes does not live long

Answer (score 2):

You could go with (abstract) classes, but interfaces are possible too. In that case, making the factory itself generic seems like the wrong move. Make the contract type generic instead. After a bit of playing around, I was able to puzzle this together:

```
interface Contract { }

interface Factory<A extends any[], C extends Contract> {
    deploy: (...args: A) => C;
}

// Some helper types
type FactoryArgs<F extends Factory<any, any>> = F extends Factory<infer A, any> ? A : never;
type FactoryContractType<F extends Factory<any, any>> = F extends Factory<any, infer C> ? C : never;

interface FactoryForClass<C extends new (...args: any) => Contract> {
    //deploy: C extends new (...args: infer A) => infer T ? Factory<A, T>['deploy'] : never;
    deploy: Factory<ConstructorParameters<C>, InstanceType<C>>['deploy'];
}

class CustomContract implements Contract {
    constructor(a: number, b: number) { }
}

class CustomFactory implements FactoryForClass<typeof CustomContract> {
    deploy(x: number, y: number): CustomContract {
        return new CustomContract(x, y);
    }
}

type MockContract<C extends Contract> = Contract & C & {
    mockProperty: number;
}

type MockFactory<F extends Factory<any, any>> = F & {
    deploy: (...args: FactoryArgs<F>) => MockContract<FactoryContractType<F>>;
}

const mockFactory: MockFactory<CustomFactory> = {
    deploy(a: number, b: number) {
        const customContract = new CustomContract(a, b);
        const result: CustomContract & MockContract<CustomContract> = customContract as any;
        result.mockProperty = 123;
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kelvin! That's a great and cleaner solution. The issue is that I don't have any way of modifying the Contract, Factory, CustomContract, or the CustomFactory. This is because I am building a [mocking library](https://github.com/defi-wonderland/smock) that wraps them

Comment: @0xGorilla That does indeed complicate things. You should still be able to use my `type MockFactory<...> = ...`, as it bypasses the "type loop" in your original `MockFactory` interface. Basically, the answer you posted yourself.

Comment: @0xGorilla even if answer was not full but was helpfull please dont forget to upvote it - like I did. It may help other people.